# SwiftUI ForEach, conditionals and showing one result of many

Tags: swiftui, foreach, conditional-statements

I have an interesting looping and conditional problem that I’m having trouble solving.

```
struct ForEachLoopTesting: View {
    
    let start = ["a", "b", "c", "a"]
    let this = ["a", "b"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(start, id:\.self) { test1 in
                ForEach(start, id:\.self) { test2 in
                    if [test1, test2] == this {
                        Text("true") // this prints twice…how can I get to print only once?
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can show the first result of the multiple results that meet the condition? Or maybe I'm approaching this wrong and there's a better way?

Comment: when you use `ForEach(start, id:\.self)` it means the element of `start` are supposed to be unique.
They are not, you have "a" twice. This is why it shows two `true`.
Change one of the "a" to "d" and you will see the expected results.
In other words ensure that the elements of the array are unique. As the warning says, "...the ID a occurs multiple times within the collection, this will give undefined results!"

Comment: that second "a" is intended to be there. I know there will be two or more conditions that will be true, but what I want is to print the first of how ever many meet the condition.

Comment: then I believe you are using the wrong construct (ForEach) to achieve what you want. The warning says clearly, "...the ID `a` occurs multiple times within the collection, this will give undefined results!"

Comment: basically I have the 'start' array and I want to see if that array contains the matched pair from 'this' variable, and then if it does, I'll do something. Also the 'start' array will contain one or more of the same string values. Easiest case is like you said, all values are unique, but that won't be the only case for the 'start' array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try something like this approach, without using the `ForEach` loop (because they require the entries to be unique):

```
struct ForEachLoopTesting: View {
    
    let start = ["a", "b", "c", "a"]
    let this = ["a", "b"]
    
    var body: some View {
        if startContains(this) {
            Text("yes start contains this")
        } else {
            Text("no start does not contain this")
        }
    }
    
    func startContains(_ this: [String]) -> Bool {
        var result = false
        outerLoop: for test1 in start {
          for test2 in start {
             if ([test1, test2] == this) {
                result = true
                break outerLoop
             }
          }
      }
      return result
    }

// alternative
func startContains2(_ this: [String]) -> Bool {
    for test in this {
        if !start.contains(test) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
    
}
```

Comment: While both answers solve the original question, this one gets me closer to the result I am trying to achieve with a little less code. I thought I might need a break somewhere and was trying to read up on it. Thank you @workingdog

Answer (score 0):

You should not manage this inside the body of the view. Instead, it could be easier to leave the logic to a supporting function and ask SwiftUI to render the final result on the screen.

The example below separates the logic from the view's body:

```
struct ForEachLoopTesting: View {
    
    let start = ["a", "b", "c", "a"]
    let this = ["a", "b"]
    
    // Supporting function
    private var merged: [[String]] {
        var merged = [[String]]()
        
        start.forEach { test1 in
            start.forEach { test2 in
                let item = [test1, test2]
                
                // Check for both: the condition and that
                // the pair is not yet included in the array
                if item == this && !merged.contains(item) {
                    merged.append([test1, test2])
                }
            }
        }
        return merged
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            // Read and show the final result
            ForEach(merged, id:\.self) { item in
                HStack {
                    Text(item[0])
                    Text(item[1])
                    Text("true")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for this. I knew I needed to separate logic from the body, but couldn't figure out how to put together the function to do it. This answer is very helpful.